# Setting logback property via spring config + environment variable in spring config

Tags: spring, spring-boot, logback

I want to configure logback in such way that some specific appender will work only if system variable LOGGER_ENABLED is set to true. If the variable is not set at all it should not give any error.
So I tried several approaches
1. Set only env variable and use it in logback as

```
<if condition='${LOGGER_ENABLED}'>
    <then>
        <appender-ref ref="MyAppender"/>
    </then>
</if>
```

it works fine if variable is set to true of false. If it is absent - it throws error like ...is undefined
2. Another catch is to use spring yml file and set it like

```
sendErrors=${LOGGER_ENABLED:false} //that means to use false if not set
```

and in logback to use like

```
<if condition='${sendErrors}'>
    <then>
        <appender-ref ref="MyAppender"/>
    </then>
</if>
```

in such way it will work only for static "false" or "true" values and do not prefetch ${LOGGER_ENABLED:false} condition.

Is it possible to perform such configuraiton with spring boot and logback?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, I found the answer on my question.
In logback file default separator is ":-" instead of ":" in general spring boot file.
After replacing separator to ":-" I'm able to specify default value exactly in logback file
Example

```
<if condition='${sendErrors:-true}'>
    <then>
        <appender-ref ref="MyAppender"/>
    </then>
</if>
```

Comment: Can you give a code example, I have the same problem.  Thank you

Comment: ${LOGGER_ENABLED:-false} - this is example of default value

Comment: full code please

Comment: Example is added

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to configure this in your `logback.xml`. Something like:

```
<logger name="com.myorg.foo" level="${logging.level.com.myorg.foo}" additivity="false">
    <!-- <appender-ref ref="console" /> -->
    <appender-ref ref="MyAppender" />
</logger>
```

where `logging.level.com.myorg.foo` is a property you defined in `logback.xml` like your variable `LOGGER_ENABLED`

```
  <property name="logging.level.com.myorg.foo" value="ERROR"/>
```

Comment: In such way, it will be hardcoded in logback file instead of being configured by ENV variables. This doesn't allow any flexibility

Comment: It should still work if overridden with system ENV variables.

Comment: No luck :( It still shows the same error if not avaialble in env variable. Like Failed to parse condition [LOGGER_ENABLED_IS_UNDEFINED]

Comment: How is the `logback.xml` file loaded in your app? I think it has to do with the order of priority the properties/config are getting loaded. Can you try passing the argument `-Dlogging.config=[path_to_your_logback_file]]/logback.xml` and see if it can read the property values?

Comment: Yes, it seems that logback is loaded prior to the property file. Need to check where I need to change place of loading these two files. Thanks for idea